# unable to fetch data in android (retrofit) by hit endpoint url from api

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

This is my API url
http://bus.malastelecom.in/api/product/search.php?source=anandapur&destination=medinipur
where i am passing two value one is "*source*" and other is "**destination**" and it is give me a json. array object but i cant  fetch the value in my android app by help of Retrofit.
I am creating ApiClient.java class
///

```
package com.infowals.bustime.api;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class  ApiClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL ="http://bus.malastelecom.in/";
    private static ApiClient instance = null;
    private APIinterface myApi;

    private ApiClient() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        myApi = retrofit.create(APIinterface.class);
    }

    public static synchronized ApiClient getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ApiClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public APIinterface getMyApi() {
        return myApi;
    }
}
```

***BusDetails.java*** as a model class

```
package com.infowals.bustime.api;

import com.infowals.bustime.model.BusSearchResponce;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface APIinterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/product/search.php")
    Call<List<BusSearchResponce>>busSearchResponce(
            @Field("source") String source,
            @Field("destination") String destination

    );


}
```

and ***BusSearchResponce.java*** class for responce

```
package com.infowals.bustime.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class BusSearchResponce {
    //private BusDetails busDetails;



    @SerializedName("busDetails")
    @Expose
    private List<BusDetails> busDetails = null;

    public List<BusDetails> getBusDetails() {
        return busDetails;
    }
    public void setBusDetails(List<BusDetails> busDetails) {
        this.busDetails = busDetails;
    }
}
```

and ***MainActivity.java*** for MainActivity

// i want to show data which is fetch using a tost or another activity

```
package com.infowals.bustime.Activity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.infowals.bustime.R;
import com.infowals.bustime.api.ApiClient;
import com.infowals.bustime.model.BusDetails;
import com.infowals.bustime.model.BusSearchResponce;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editTextSource;
    private EditText editTextDestination;
    private Button busSearchButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //getSupportActionBar().hide();
    editTextSource = findViewById(R.id.editTextSourceId);
    editTextDestination = findViewById(R.id.editTextDestinationId);
    busSearchButton = findViewById(R.id.search_buses);

    final String source = editTextSource.getText().toString().trim();
    final String destination = editTextDestination.getText().toString().trim();

    busSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), destination, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Call<List<BusSearchResponce>> call= ApiClient
                .getInstance().getMyApi().busSearchResponce(source,destination);
      call.enqueue(new Callback<List<BusSearchResponce>>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<List<BusSearchResponce>> call, Response<List<BusSearchResponce>> response) {
             BusSearchResponce busSearchResponce = (BusSearchResponce) response.body();
              // i want to show data which is fetch using a tost
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i want to show data in here" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              
              
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<List<BusSearchResponce>> call, Throwable t) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
    }
});
    }


}
```

and ***APIinterface.java class***
///

```
package com.infowals.bustime.api;

import com.infowals.bustime.model.BusSearchResponce;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface APIinterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/product/search.php")
    Call<List<BusSearchResponce>>busSearchResponce(
            @Field("source") String source,
            @Field("destination") String destination

    );


}
```

***ActivityMain.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.infowals.bustime.Activity.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#512da8"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_outline_white_24dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="260dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/bus_image_1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/print_clearly"
                        android:text="Hey user!"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="32sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/gotham"
                        android:text="Where you want to go."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-44dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:contentPadding="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:textColorHint="#FF8A99AF">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextSourceId"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_on_light_blue_24dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/calibri"
                                android:hint="Source"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />
                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:textColorHint="#FF8A99AF">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextDestinationId"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_on_light_blue_24dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/calibri"
                                android:hint="Destination"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />
                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:textColorHint="#FF8A99AF">


                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search_buses"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/calibri"
                    android:text="Search Buses"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

***and its look like***

[ActivityMain.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNMoW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use body for send data to api:

```
public class MyBody
{
    public String source;
    public String destination;
}
```

Set the data to object

```
MyBody mybody= new MyBody();
mybody.source= "source";
mybody.destination= "destination";
```

Call your api

```
@POST("api/login")
Call<List<BusSearchResponce>> busSearchResponce(@Body MyBody mybody);
```

Comment: sorry sir i want to pass two value in two key one is source and other is destination and value of those key is wile be taken from user

Comment: ok you can get that from user and make body model and then send it for server what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the value need to pass in to the url, use method **GET** and pass it through **Query**. Your api interface should be like this

```
public interface APIinterface {
     @GET("api/product/search.php") 
     Call<BusSearchResponce> busSearchResponce(@Query("source") String source, @Query("destination") String destination ); 
}
```